# How can we send data to a websocket client side function?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In play-scala websocket using Iteratee how can we send data to a websocket client side function?  How can we specify the function in scala before doing the channel push?

My current websocket server code is as follows :

```
lazy val (out, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String] def connect = WebSocket.using[String] { request => val in = Iteratee.foreach[String] {
      msg => println(msg)
        channel push("I received your message: " + msg)
    }
    (in,out)   
}
```

My current client code is as follow:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/connect.ws");   
ws.onopen = function(){
      console.log("Socket has been opened! ");  
};
ws.onmessage = function(message) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(message.data)) 
};
```

Every time I send a message using “channel push”, “ws.onmessage” is getting triggered. How can I emit/trigger the custom event in client side from server side?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Give some sample, of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Question is too vague. Give some code examples or specifics of what you're trying to do. In particular this part: "send data to a websocket client side function" doesn't make a lot of sense without more context.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear in my question. I implemented a websocket using play-scala. My socket client is a web application and I’m using “angular-reconnecting-websocket.js” framework to communicate to websocket server. I have edited and update my question too. Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks!